# Use preg_replace

Tags: php

What is the simplest way to change

```
<a href="link">title</a>
```

into

```
[url="link"]title[/url]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offering improved version:
1) will consider both '" as argument enclosures
2) will work with multiple tags
3) allows for other params in the a tag and various spacing

```
<?php
$r = "<a href=\"test.html\" arg2=\"foo\" bar3=\"_something_else\">test</a>\n
<a href= \"test2.html\" >test2</a>\n
<a href = 'test3.html'>test3</a>\n
";
$r = preg_replace("/<a.*?href[^=]*=[^'\"]*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"].*?>([^<]+)<\/a>/", "[url=\\1]\\2[/url]", $r);
echo $r;
```

output:

```
[url=test.html]test[/url]

[url=test2.html]test2[/url]

[url=test3.html]test3[/url]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to remove a target="_blank" from the a tag when turning this into the output? That is my problem atm.

Comment: Also, I know it's a completely different subject, but when I have <br /> in the html, how can I remove this and make it visually look like new line to the user?

Comment: above regex would already strip any other params try yourself ;) it will work

Comment: about <br /> -- convert to \n

Comment: I don't really understand these expressions. It's [url=link], there are no " ". Can you make the alterations?

Comment: in output there are no " ", but I assumed those could be in the HTML which you are converting to the format that you asked for.

Comment: Yes but I don't want it to bud. I want the " taken out. I just don't understand the / enough to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

`$result = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/', '[url="\1"]\2[/url]', $input);`

Comment: I'm getting the following error with that. Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'a'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the slash in `</a>`. I've just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this Expression: `#<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#s`.

Example:

```
$str = '<a href="link">title</a>';
$str = preg_replace( '#<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#s', '[url="\\1"]\\2[/url]', $str);
```

Demo: [Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kOWg57)